# How to get contents of child tag of a parent tag in xml using php

Tags: php, xml

I'm trying to get the content of a tag that is within another tag together with a specifig ID tag. The source is the below xml response:

**The Xml response is here**

```
<PricePlans>
    <PricePlan>
        <Description>Check Email</Description>
        <ID>1</ID>
        <Price>2</Price>
        <Time>900</Time>
    </PricePlan>
    <PricePlan>
        <Description>High Speed</Description>
        <ID>2</ID>
        <Price>5</Price>
        <Time>3600</Time>
    </PricePlan>
</PricePlans>
```

**my php code is here:**

```
echo "Desc" ." ".$xml->PricePlan->Description ."</br>";
```

This code gives me the content of the first "Description" tag (Check Email) but I want the description of a priceplan with a specifig "ID" tag (e.g. ID 2 - "High Speed")
The xml response might have even more "PricePlan" tags but each has a unique value in the "ID" tag.

Answer (score 1):

You can access them the same as array:

```
echo($xml->PricePlan[0]->Description);
//Check Email
echo($xml->PricePlan[1]->Description);
//High Speed

foreach ($xml->PricePlan as $pricePlan) {
    echo($pricePlan->Description);
}
//Check Email
//High Speed
```

If you need to find element by value in ID you may use xpath:

```
$el = $xml->xpath('/PricePlans/PricePlan/ID[text()=2]/..');
```

Answer (score 1):

To take the Description of an element with a particular ID you can use xpath.

```
$id = 2;

// xpath method always returns an array even when it matches only one element,
// so if ID is unique you can always take the 0 element
$description = $xml->xpath("/PricePlans/PricePlan/ID[text()='$id']/../Description")[0];

echo $description; // this echoes "High Speed"
```